# docker pull на удалённой машине

Tags: docker, jenkins

Почему при выполнении скрипта по `ssh` в `jenkins`, я не могу залогиниться в докере и запулить образы `docker login 1.2.3.4:5 -u 123 --password 456` ?

```
Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY`
[SSH] completed
[SSH] exit-status: 1

Build step 'Execute shell script on remote host using ssh' marked build as failure
```

---

[here](http://www.javaclix.com/2019/01/how-to-fix-cannot-perform-interactive.html)

```
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
```

---

[here](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/118)

```
Credentials store docker-credential-pass exited with "exit status 2: gpg: decryption failed: No secret key".
```

---

https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/439#issuecomment-461836102

---

Credentials store docker-credential-pass exited with "exit status 2: gpg: decryption failed: No secret key".

[Решается](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers) удалением `docker-credential-pass` из PATH.

Comment: Очень странно. По ошибке видно, что ругань происходит на параметр $DISPLAY, причет там еще какой то autolaunch упоминается. Обычно в docker никакие $DISPLAY не нужны и вообще не предполагается наличия gui - окружения. Может, это какой то чисто jenkins'овский прикол? Я бы попробовал сделать ssh на ту машину и ввести все команды руками. Я так понимаю, вопрос относится именно к тому, чтобы (потом, когда всё заработает) jenkins делал это автоматом?

Comment: @S.H. конечно. Автоматом я это делаю без проблем ежедневно